# gdal_translate ERROR 6: Too many command options

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, anaconda, timesat

I'm using GDAL 3.3.1 on Windows 10 through Anaconda. I'm trying to convert a TIMESAT binary file to a .tif, which I've been able to do before. However, when I enter this code:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff C:\timesat33\run\01 corners\01tl\01tlamp_season1 01tlamp_season1.tif
```

I get the error message

```
ERROR 6: Too many command options '01tlamp_season1.tif'
```

followed by a list of usage options. I'm not sure why this isn't working, since this code worked for a different file:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff C:\timesat33\run\1315sos_season1 1315sos_season1.tif
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: The spaces in the path are the issue. Is the first input `C:\timesat33\run\01` or `C:\timesat33\run\01 corners\01tl\01tlamp_season1`??

Comment: @MikeT That worked! Thank you, I wasn't aware that spaces aren't allowed in Anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was said by Mike T in the comments, but I can't add that as the answer to the post. The issue was the space in `...\run\01 corners\...`, and has been remedied by changing it to `...\run\01corners\...`.

Comment: It should work also as `gdal_translate -of GTiff "C:\timesat33\run\01 corners\01tl\01tlamp_season1" 01tlamp_season1.tif`.